Power Platform deploying From Test to Prod
my company is just starting to utilize Power Platform and I have been put in charge but have no previous experience.
I am implementing Power Platform Pipelines and am specifically having issues deploying from Test to Prod. Test is a Sandbox and Prod is a Production Environment.
and
I am using environment variables to manage dynamic content, so I can easily switch between Test and Production. For example, I can point to a Test SharePoint site, pull its Title dynamically, and the same process works when I switch to test the Production SharePoint site. However, when I deploy to Production, I encounter multiple errors, including messages like: 'Item.item/Title' is no longer present in the operation schema. It should be removed before the workflow is re-saved.'
Despite the environment variable successfully updating to point to the correct Production site, the dynamic content in the Production environment is not being updated as expected. The same approach works fine in Test, but it doesn’t seem to update properly in Production. What could be causing this issue?

You got any screenshots?
